# How to efficiently determine which point of spherical octahedron is closest

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Given the following spherical octahedron with 3 grid points and one point p randomly within the 1-2-3 tile

[image]

how do I determine which of the points 1, 2, or 3 is geodesically closest to p without computing scalar products? I am actually interested in the scalar product of p with the closest point only. This is part of an algorithm where the evaluation of the scalar product is a bottleneck, so I wonder if there is some tweak to that.

Comment: That's a surprising bottleneck. Do you have a huge number of queries/dataset, or a special representation of your point coordinates? In the latter case, it'd be useful to share it. Also, if you really have a sphere in euclidean space, you could reduce to euclidean distance instead of looking at geodesics. There's an angle $0\le\theta\le\pi$ such that the geodesic distance is $r\theta$, and the euclidean distance $2r\sin\frac\theta2$. Since you don't want scalar products, I guess euclidean distance is also a no-go though... Can you give more details on the allowed operations?

Comment: How is your point $p$ given? If you have cartesian coordinates in a system that aligns with your red points, you can figure out which of the points to use simply by checking which coordinate of $p$ is absolutely largest -- and the absolute value of that coordinate is then _also_ the scalar product you want.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. This question is a huge boildown of my original problem which is highly specific. The answer of @Aretino is very much what I had in mind and can probably be adapted to my actual needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume point $P$ given by its latitude $\lambda$ and longitude $\phi$, point $1$ being located at $\lambda=90°$, point $2$ at $\lambda=0°$ and $\phi=0°$, point $3$ at $\lambda=0°$ and $\phi=90°$.

The center $O$ of the triangle has coordinates $(1/\sqrt3,1/\sqrt3,1/\sqrt3)$ corresponding to $\lambda=\arcsin(1/\sqrt3)$ and $\phi=45°$. Joining $O$ with the centers $M$, $H$, $N$ of arcs $12$, $23$, $31$ respectively, we can divide the triangle into three sectors: finding which vertex is the nearest to $P$ is the same as finding to which sector $P$ belongs.

The greatest circle arc $OM$ is formed by points with longitude $0°\le\phi\le45°$ and latitude $\theta=\arctan(\cos\phi)$, while arc $ON$ is formed by points with longitude $45°\le\phi\le90°$ and latitude $\theta=\arctan(\sin\phi)$.

We conclude then that point $P$ is:

- nearest to vertex $2$ if $0°\le\phi\le45°$ and 
  $0°\le\theta\le\arctan(\cos\phi)$;
- nearest to vertex $3$ if $45°\le\phi\le90°$ and 
  $0°\le\theta\le\arctan(\sin\phi)$;
- nearest to vertex $1$ otherwise.